# Umbraco - Fanoe starter kit - How to make the "hamburger" menu appear instead of the nav on all screen sizes?

Tags: css, content-management-system, themes, umbraco

As per the title - given the default Fanoe starter kit for Umbraco 7, what's the best/easiest way to make the "hamburger" menu for the navigation, which appears when viewing in a mobile site, appear on all versions (i.e. desktop) regardless of screen size?

(This starter kit already comes with logic for min screen size = 992 etc but I can't seem to get the "toggle" to disregard the screen size but never show the textual navigation unless the toggle is clicked!)

The CSS that comes with the starter kit contains properties similar to the below:

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {

body {
    width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

nav {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease-in-out, opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out, opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 144px;
}
```

Edited to add: I'm aware of the usability issues of the "hamburger"; for simplicity I didn't mention it earlier but am actually planning to replace that icon with something like "OPTIONS".

Comment: Google useability of hamburger menus. Looooads of people don't even know what those three lines mean. So maybe you should reconsider?

Comment: That said, then if I'm not mistaken Fanoe is based on Twitter Bootstrap. You could try finding help in Bootstrap context instead?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/q/23641125/3668031 ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
@media (min-width: 992px){
 #toggle {
    display: none; 
}}
```

Plus vove this:

```
`-webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
-ms-transform: translateX(100%);
transform: translateX(100%);
opacity: 1;
transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease-in-out, opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out, opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
top: 144px;`
```

to nav section without @media: